# @ManyToMany mapping delete instead of updating

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

UserWorkRelatedInfo entity:

```
 @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_work_related_info_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_work_related_info_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;
```

in the Role entity i dont have specified anything !

My Hibernate logs are

```
Hibernate: 
    update
        user_work_related_info 
    set
        handover_protocol_id=?,
        lead_id=?,
        position_id=?,
        stack=?,
        user_id=? 
    where
        id=?
2023-08-03 12:50:02.127  INFO 66838 --- [0.0-8080-exec-2] e.g.erp.utils.audit.CrudEventListener    : Admin updated UserWorkRelatedInfo : {"id":11,"stack":null,"position":null,"handoverProtocol":null}
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        user_work_related_info_roles 
    where
        user_work_related_info_id=?
```

i tried with Equals() and hashCode() , also tried to add mappedBy into Role entity , i removed the orphanRemoval from User entity // ( My User entity is OneToOne with UserWorkRelatedInfo entity ) , also changed the cascade types , -- Im using entity graph for the joining . Also this happens when im updating the lead which is column is userWorkRelatedInfo

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do want do here and what problem you are facing?

Comment: I'm trying to update userWorkRelatedInfo entity and im updating its lead column , after the update of the lead column , it does this delete on my mapping table !